# Tile Not Working

Tags: ios, swift

I just started this but I'm having some trouble.
Xcode finds the method and accepts it as a selector. But whenever I tap the view nothing happens (I'm creating views via code. They appear fine on the simulator, but the gesture recognizer I added to the view doesn't work).

Inside viewDidLoad in the view controller:

```
            let tile = BoardTile(x: 0, y: 100, size: 50)
            view.addSubview(tile.view)
```

The stuff I'm trying to do

```
import UIKit

class BoardTile: NSObject{

    let view: UIView
    let label: UILabel

    init(x:Int, y:Int, size:Int){
        view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: size, height: size))
        view.backgroundColor = ViewController.baseColor
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
        label.text = "1"
        label.font = font
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        view.addSubview(label)

        //***********HELP HERE, DOESN'T WORK***********//
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        tap.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped))

    }

    func tapped(){
        // Never prints when I tap: 
        print("tapped!")
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not specifying what instance you want in the #selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What keeps the "tile" object alive? If the "tile" instance dies within the method scope, the view and the label dies with it.

Comment: This is correct. I keep make stupid mistakes. I just assumed this would work similar to Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: This wouldn't happen if you would use more typical (ios) approach. i.e. instead of having an abstract object that holds the view and label..you would inherit from UIView and implement custom code incl. the label and recognizer inside that.
What you say in the post also shows you believed all this time you ARE tapping the view and there is an issue with the tap handling, whereas actually you didn't have any view at all! To mitigate these false assumptions  in the future, use Live View Debugging and/or set temporary "debug" background colours to confirm the view is in the view hierarchy.